# Comprehension of 'he doesn't say NOT after everything'

Tags: reading-comprehension

> Bunky and I frequently watch TV program called Future Ratboy.

> I'm Future Ratboy and Bunky is his annoying sidekick, Not Bird, **except** Bunky's not a bird and he doesn't say 'NOT' after everything.

I read the cartoon 'I am not a loser'. The above is not understood by me. Here Bunky's role is a helper of name 'Not Bird'. But I am stuck with *the following part after the word except*. How can we understand ?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "Me and Bunky" is wrong here. It should be "I and Bunky" or, more commonly, "Bunky and I". I am not familiar with this cartoon so maybe this was intentionally wrong to reflect the speaker's English ability.

Comment: Thank you for your comment (And this is not one of writer and it's mine)

Comment: @Kodos Johnson : Maybe do you know the case where we use 'me and Bunky' ? Today when I saw the youtube, I met 'me and mum set up ....'

Comment: You could use me and Bunky if it's the **object** of a sentence. For example, Alice gave the cake to me and Bunky. However, if you want to say that you and Bunky gave the cake to Alice, you would have to use "I" since "Bunky and I" is the subject. For example: Bunky and I gave the cake to Alice.

Comment: The example that you mentioned ("me and mum set up") is wrong since "me and mum" is used as the subject noun so it should be "I and mum set up" or "mum and I set up". This is a common mistake even by native English speakers. One trick you can do is to remove "and mum" and see if it still sounds correct. "Me set up..." doesn't sound right. You usually would use "I" here, so it's the same when you include "and mum"

Comment: I see. Thanks for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The situation is roughly as follows: the writer and Bunky often watch the show Future Ratboy. When they watch, the writer imagines himself as Future Ratboy, and Bunky imagines himself as Not Bird.

The joke / difficulty is that the character Not Bird **is** a bird. He is called Not Bird because he is a bird who often says 'NOT'. Bunky is not a bird, and he doesn't say 'NOT', and so the writer is insinuating that Bunky is not a good fit for the role of Not Bird.

Comment: Yes. In fact there is a picture containing the helper. He is a bird and says 'NOT' in the picture. Now I understand totally. Thank you.